# How can I automate the link preview shared on social medial (MS Teams, Slack, Twitter, Whats App, LinkedIn etc)?

Tags: twitter, slack, api-linkpreview

I have some external links that I can share on different messaging apps(**Twitter/Slack/WhatsApp** etc.) like below:

> http://adobe.com/
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow

The previews are generated but how can I automate this service for different clients. By automate, I mean to verify the following:

1. Preview image is showing or not whether small or large depending upon the link?
2. The text description is coming or not?

Any feedback/input would be highly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just FYI, twitter does have a card validator https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: @S.Ramjit yes, that I saw. So you are suggesting to do automation of card validator. It is doable for twitter but do you know about other clients(Linkedin/FB/WhatsApp/Slack etc) card validator?

Comment: Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ 
LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

The others I'm not sure about